# Azure Devops Yaml Python Script task: PythonScriptV0 , how to pass arrays as the field supports only a strings

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am trying to pass to a python scripts 3 parameters one of them is an array, this works when i run the script locally, i am using sys.argv to achieve this.

However the argument field support only strings as far i can see. How can i go around this any ideas? Thanks

the array is ${{ parameters.packageVersion }}

Code:

```
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Modify ansible inventory files (wms_common.yml) with deployed versions'
    inputs:
      scriptSource: filePath
      scriptPath: deployment/s/azure-devops/scripts/script.py
      arguments: |
          ../../inventories/${{ variables.inventory }}/group_vars/all/wms_common.yml
          ../../inventories/central/${{ variables.inventory }}/group_vars/all/wms_common.yml
          ${{ parameters.packageVersion }}
```

Error:

> /azure-devops/wms.full.pipeline.yml (Line: 95, Col: 18): Unable to convert from Array to String. Value: Array

Edit: Reframed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below YAML will help you convert the array to String objects and use them.

```
variables:
  myVariable1: 'value1'
  myVariable2: 'value2'
  system.debug: true

parameters:
- name: InstanceArgs 
  type: object
  default: [1,2] 

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
        import argparse 

        parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Test")
        parse.add_argument("test1")
        parse.add_argument("test2")
        args = parse.parse_args()
        print(args.test1)
        print(args.test2)
        print('this is a test.')
    # arguments: $(myVariable1) $(myVariable2)'
    arguments: ${{join(' ',parameters.InstanceArgs)}}
```

You need to use the join expression in YAML to get the elements:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#join

[image]

Comment: thanks, i didn't have to modify the code to use argparse, i just used the join expression on my third parameter, and then edited my script to seperate them to array again, thanks for the idea. So join was the solution